# How to apply Abstract Factory Pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

I am new to design patterns and I have a scenario here. I am not sure as how to implement the pattern.

1. We have multiple vendors Philips, Onida, etc.
2. Each vendor (philips, onida, etc) may have different types of product i.e. Plasma or Normal TV.

I want specific product of each vendor using Abstract Factory Pattern.

My implementation so far:

```
public enum TvType
{
    Samsung = 0, LG = 1, Philips = 2, Sony = 3
}

public enum Product
{
    Plasma = 0, NormalTV = 1
}
```

Concrete class of each vendor that returns each product and also the interface that contains ProductInfo i.e. if Vendor is *that* then it must have *this* product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pseudocode it could be something like this:

```
interface TvFactory {
  NormalTelevision createNormalTv();
  PlasmaTelevision createPlasmaTv();
}

class PhilipsTvFactory implements TvFactory {
  public NormalTelevision createNormalTv() {
    return new PhilipsNormalTelevision();
  }
  public PlasmaTelevision createPlasmaTv() {
    return new PhilipsPlasmaTelevision();
  }
}

class OnidaTvFactory implements TvFactory {
  public NormalTelevision createNormalTv() {
    return new OnidaNormalTelevision();
  }
  public PlasmaTelevision createPlasmaTv() {
    return new OnidaPlasmaTelevision();
  }
}

// similarly for other vendors...

...
// decides - maybe based on config - which factory to use
TvFactory factory = loadTvFactory();
Television myTv = factory.createPlasmaTv();
```

Comment: In terms of deciding which factory to use, make the class that needs to use the factory abstract, and extending classes provide the factory that is then acquired by the base class by a call to its abstract getTvFactory method.

Comment: @Finbarr, that is one way to go, although I prefer a separate factory loader class. This makes the code reusable.

Comment: This is crazy bloat. and the difference between all those factories will just be a single enumerator value after the `new` is called ? Waw, awesome software engineering here. Please re-read your [SOLID](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SOLIDPrinciples.aspx) principles.

Comment: @v.oddou, please check the OP. The task was to apply the Abstract Factory pattern. And yes, this is an intentionally simplistic example, apt for learning the basics of this pattern - not production code. Thus your criticism is totally off the mark.

Answer (score 0):

Enums are evil. Replace them with interfaces:

```
public interface IVendor { /*...*/ }
```

you can then provide concrete implementations of IVender for each of your vendors.

```
public class Samsung : IVendor { /*...*/ }

public class Philips : IVendor { /*...*/ }

public class Sony : IVendor { /*...*/ }
```

It's not clear to my why you are asking about Abstract Factory, or what it is you want to be able to do exactly...

Comment: Enums can implement interfaces :-)

Comment: @Finbarr, in some languages, yes. However, the language is not specified here. Judging from the code excerpt, it is not C++, neither Java - could it be C# ?

Comment: Hey @Mark - As I mentioned earlier that I am new to pattern world... so just wanted to know how Abstract pattern can be implemented on such scenario.... nothing else... n e ways Thanks for u r comments.

Comment: this is not a relationale database, why would vendors require classes, they will end up empty, this is bloat. And 3 factories are not needed, obviously just one is needed (for the TV type) and a Parse method on the TV class would set the vendor and other members correctly. [interface segregation](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ISP.aspx) + [liskov](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/LSP.aspx)